# Use KendoUI tree view as input value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I am using [Kendo UI TreeView](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index) along with *Kendo UI MVC Wrappers* in my *ASP.NET MVC* project.

I have HTML form in my view. Here is the code of my **view**:

```
<form method="POST" action="@Url.Action("Review")">
    @* ... *@
    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("CategoryId")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Read(read => read.Action("Categories", "ReviewCategories"))
        )
    )
    @* ... *@
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The tree view is working perfectrly. Here is the code of `Categories` **action**:

```
public JsonResult Categories(int? id)
{
    var categories = this.forumCategoriesService.All()
       .Where(x => id.HasValue ? x.ParentId == id : x.ParentId == null)
       .Select(x => new { id = x.Id, Name = x.Title, hasChildren = x.Children.Any() });

    return this.Json(categories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The **problem is** that when I click `submit` button the form sends all data except the value of the selected `CategoryId`.

What is the most elegand way to make the Kendo UI TreeView send `CategoryId` when I submit the form?

(If there is no easy way to send it as an input value, I will accept any custom JavaScript code solutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a **workaround**.

**First:** Create hidden input with the desired parameter:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CategoryId" id="CategoryId" value="@Model.CategoryId" />
```

**Second:** Add `on select` event handler for the tree view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("CategoryIdTreeView")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .Events(ev => ev.Select("onCategorySelect"))     @* <--------------- *@
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read.Action("Categories", "ReviewCategories"))
    )
)
```

**Third:** Implement the handler and change the value of `#CategoryId` in it

```
function onCategorySelect(ev) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(ev.node);
    var categoryId = dataItem.id;
    $("#CategoryId").val(categoryId);
}
```

If anyone knows better solution please be welcome to add another answer.